# HeIp understanding Fibonacci Search

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search, fibonacci

On the internet I only find code for the algorithm but I need understand in form of text first because I have trouble understand things from code only. And other description of the algorithm are very complicated for me (on Wikipedia and other sites).

Here is what I understand for far:

Let say we want search in array the element `10`:

```
Index i  0  1   2   3    4
         2  3   4  10   40
```

Some fibonacci number here:

```
Index j  0  1   2   3    4    5    6    7    8    9
         0  1   1   2    3    5    8    13   21   34
```

First thing we do is find fibonacci number that is greater-equal to array length. Array length is `4` so we need take fibonacci number `5` that is in index position `j=5`.

But where we divide the array now and how continue? I really don't understand it.. Please help understand for exam...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm goes in the following way:
The length of the array is 5, so the fibonacci number which is greater than or equal to 5 is 5. The two numbers which are preceding in the Fibonacci sequence are 2 [n-2] and 3 [n-1] - (2, 3, 5).

So, arr[n-2] i.e. arr[2] is compared with the number to be searched which is 10.

If the element is smaller than the number, then the sequence is shifted 1 time to the left. Also, the previous index is saved for next iteration to give an offset for the index. In this case, since 4 is smaller, n-2 becomes 1 (1, 2, 3). arr[1 + 2(prev)] = arr[3] = 10. So, the index of the number is 3.

If the element is larger, the sequence is shifted 2 times to the left.

Always the min(n-2+offset,n)th element is compared with number to get the matching result.